# Previous commits are appearing in a new branch in git

Tags: git, github, git-branch, pull-request

I've been given several tasks, and each task should be pushed it its own branches. For example, task_1 files into task_1 branch. I've created branches from task_1 to task_8 for each task. 
However, before working on a specific task, let's say task_3, I created a new branch for task_3 by `git branch -M task_3`. Then, I created a folder named `task_3` and kept all files related to the task there. Having finished the task, I did: `git add task_3` and `git commit -m "task 3 finished"` and `git push origin task_3`. 
The funny thing is all the previous commits (`task_1` and `task_2`) were pushed to `task_3` branch. For example, in `task_8` branch, all the previous commits were also pushed to `task_8` however I added only `task_8` folder to the staging area then made a commit and push.

Is there any way to ignore previous branches and commits when pushing files to each lastly created branch?

The repo is [here](https://github.com/jkalandarov/epam_stage_1).

Also, I am asked to create a pull request on each branch and files should be added to the `main` branch before merging. How am I supposed to do that?

I appreciate your help.

Comment: Why are you using the `-M` flag with `git branch`? I think that's the cause of your problems.

Comment: "Then, I created a folder named task_3 and kept all files related to the task there" - that's not how you're meant to use branches in git. Git is nothing like SVN or TFS: branches don't exist as a subdirectory within the repo's filesystem, instead a git branch is an entirely separate timeline: like a parallel-universe.

Comment: "Is there any way to ignore previous branches and commits when pushing files to each lastly created branch?" - because you wrote this, I'm guessing you're _not_ familiar with how git's object-store works? (because a commit references its parents (back to the initial commit) by content-addressable-storage based on a hash of the contents of a commit (so you cannot  "ignore" previous commits: they _have_ to exist everywhere or you'll need to rebase or squash, both of which intentionally cause information-loss), and secondarily, one does not "push files". A commit is not a file.

Comment: So, the previous commits to other branches will always be displayed in all of the branches?

Comment: "previous commits to other branches will always be displayed in all of the branches" <--No. You are still misunderstanding how git's branch model works. It would be difficult for me to explain in a StackOverflow comment, but my recommendation is to get a _decent_ git GUI (Visual Studio's built-in git tooling is still awful, and GitHub's web UI is also lacking) such as Git Kraken or SourceTree, because both of those let you actually see every branch _simultaneously_ in a unified timeline view (i.e. you can see all "parallel-universes" at once) - and that really helped me when I was new to git.